# How to make ticker(animated text) in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I need to do button with animated text like on picture. I think it would be custom widget - `StackPane` with `Button` and animated `Text`. Yes? And how to realise showing/hiding logic for text. Any ideas? Thanks[image]

Comment: The user wants a different kind of marquee, where the Text reappears (from the opposite corner) before getting completely lost at either side ! In the mentioned answer, the text reappears only after getting lost completely ! I am not sure, if it is possible !